# Footer Visible only after resizing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a footer that should be fixed on the bottom of the page. The footer is creating but visible only after resizing the window. Below is my code

```
<div id="footerContainerLexApp">
  <div id="footerTitleBar" class="bold footerTitleBar">
    <div>
      <div class="form-group-margin">
        <button type="button" class="btn-primary uiBMarginRight btn btn-root" style="min-width: 100px;">Save</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn-primary uiBMarginRight btn btn-root" style="min-width: 100px;">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.footerTitleBar {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 0 20px 20px;
}
```

There is also a function that is been called every time the window is resized.

```
onResize: function () {
  if(lexAppWidget.jqueryLoaded) {
    var heightToBeReduced = 200;
    if($("#tabviewMainContainerLexApp").is(":visible")) {
      heightToBeReduced = 200;
    }
    var height = top && top.innerHeight ? top.innerHeight - heightToBeReduced : 800;
    if(widget.containerScroller) {
      widget.containerScroller.setSize({ height: height });
    }
    if($(".commonGridTable").length != 0) {
      for(var i = 0; i < $(".commonGridTable").length; i++) {
        if($($(".commonGridTable")[i]).attr('id') && $("#" + $($(".commonGridTable")[i]).attr('id').split("idCommonGridTable")[1]).is(':visible')) {
          var containerWidth = widget.getElement("#" + $($(".commonGridTable")[i]).attr('id').split("idCommonGridTable")[1]).getSize().width
          var widgetWidthonResize = (containerWidth - (0.02 * containerWidth));
          $($(".commonGridTable")[i]).setGridWidth(widgetWidthonResize);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Use {position:fixed; bottom:0;}

Comment: that worked... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would consider calling `onResize()` in your `onLoad()`...
It's a common approach, if the `onResize` method contains some logic...